# Not getting any output - webscraping using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from the following website. For the year 1993, for eg, this is the link.
https://www.ugc.ac.in/jobportal/search.aspx?tid=MTk5Mw==

Firstly, I am not sure how to navigate between the pages as the url for every page is the same.
Secondly, I wrote the following code to scrape information on any given page.

```
url = "https://www.ugc.ac.in/jobportal/search.aspx?tid=MTk5Mw=="
File = []
response = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(response.text,"html.parser")
entries = soup.find_all('tr',{'class': 'odd'})
    
for entry in entries:
    columns = {}
    
    Cells = entry.find_all("td")
    columns['Gender'] = Cells[3].get_text()
    columns['Category'] = Cells[4].get_text()
    columns['Subject'] = Cells[5].get_text()
    columns['NET Qualified'] = Cells[6].get_text()
    columns['Month/Year'] = Cells[7].get_text()
    
    File.append(columns)

df = pd.DataFrame(File)
df
```

I am not getting any error while running the code but I am not getting any output. I cant figure out what mistake I am doing here. Would appreciate any inputs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All data is stored inside `<script>` on that HTML page. To read it into panda's dataframe you can use next example:

```py
import re
import requests
import pandas as pd


url = "https://www.ugc.ac.in/jobportal/search.aspx?tid=MTk5Mw=="

html_doc = requests.get(url).text
data = re.search(r'"aaData":(\[\{.*?\}]),', html_doc, flags=re.S).group(1)
df = pd.read_json(data)

print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
                ugc_net_ref_no                          candidate_name  roll_no                                     subject  gender  jrf_lec  cat  vh_ph      dob                                fname                          mname                                                                                                                       address     exam_date result_date  emailid  mobile_no  subject_code  year
0               1/JRF (DEC.93)             SHRI VEERENDRA KUMAR SHARMA  N035010                                   ECONOMICS    Male      JRF  GEN    NaN      NaN             SHRI SATYA NARAIN SHARMA                           None                                                                                       27 E KARANPUR (PRAYAG) ALLAHABAD U.P.     19th DEC.93        NULL      NaN        NaN           NaN  1993
1              1/JRF (JUNE,93)                           SH MD TARIQUE  R020005                                   ECONOMICS    Male      JRF  GEN    NaN      NaN                       MD. ZAFIR ALAM                           None                                                                                             D-32, R.M. HALL, A.M.U. ALIGARH    20th June,93        NULL      NaN        NaN           NaN  1993
2              10/JRF (DEC.93)                       SHRI ARGHYA GHOSH  A245015                                   ECONOMICS    Male      JRF  GEN    NaN      NaN                 SHRI BHOLANATH GHOSH                           None                                            C/O SH.B. GHOSH 10,BAMACHARAN GHOSH LANE P.O.-BHADRESWAR,DIST.HOOGHLY CALCUTTA-24.   19th DEC.93        NULL      NaN        NaN           NaN  1993
3             10/JRF (JUNE,93)                       SH SANTADAS GHOSH  T210024                                   ECONOMICS    Male      JRF  GEN    NaN      NaN                   SHRI HARIDAS GHOSH                           None                                                               P-112, MOTILAL COLONY, NO.-1 P.O. DUM DUM, CALCUTTA - 700 028    20th June,93        NULL      NaN        NaN           NaN  1993

...
```

and saves `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working! But I dont understand how. Could you explain what is script? Or if you could direct me to some source where I can read about it...